# I can't get partials in mustache when using it with go fiber template engine

Tags: go, mustache, go-fiber

I'm trying to create a layout for my website where I use partials for my header and footer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{{title}}</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href='/static/css/global.css' rel='stylesheet'>   
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik' rel='stylesheet'>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{> views/partials/header }}
        {{{embed}}}
        {{> views/partials/footer }}
    </body>
</html>
```

I followed the example as shown here: [https://docs.gofiber.io/template/mustache/](https://stackoverflow.com)

The embedding works fine, but the partials won't work.

My file structure is like this:

```
views
├── layout.mu
└── partials
    ├── header.mu
    └── footer.mu
```

Here is how I setup the app and route:

```
engine := mustache.New("./views", ".mu")
app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{Views: engine})

app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.Render("index", fiber.Map{
            "title": "index",
        }, "layout")
    })
```

And finally here is my header:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <a href="/"><img alt="" class="logo" src="/static/images/logo.png"/></a>    
    <ul class="items">
        <li>
            <a class="links" href="/product">Produkt</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="links" href="/blog">Blogg</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="links" href="/about">Om Oss</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="links contact" href="/contact">Kontakta Oss</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```